# Django application not showing local time when hosted using Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, time, timezone, datetime-format

Beginner Django programmer here.  I'm working on a Django app and am having timezone issues.  My code successfully converts time objects into local time when I run on my local server but this conversion does not work when my application is hosted on Heroku.

I am currently converting timezone using the tzlocal extension.  In my views I use the code:

```
activate(get_localzone())
```

On my local server, get_localzone() successfully returns the local time.  On the Heroku-hosted version of my application, get_localzone() returns UTC.

Here are my time settings in settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Not sure if this matters but I'm using a Postgres database:

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

Here is an example of my home view to give you a sense of how I'm using the tzlocal package:

def home(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, 'idealist/index.html')
    else:
        context = RequestContext(request)
        activate(get_localzone())
        user = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0]
        user_projects = user.projects()

```
    events = user.events()
    event_dict = SortedDict()
    string = get_localzone()

    for event in reversed(events):
        date = event.datew.astimezone(get_localzone())
        date = date.strftime("%B") + " " + str(date.day)
        if date in event_dict.keys():
            event_dict[date].append(event)
        else:
            event_dict[date] = [event]

    return render_to_response('idealist/account_home.html', {'string': string, 'user': user, 'event_dict': event_dict, 'user_projects': user_projects}, context)
```

Also, here are the other time-related packages that I'm importing:

```
from django.utils.timezone import *
import pytz
from tzlocal import *
import datetime
from pytz import timezone
```

Thank you so much for your help.  If there is any other information I can provide you with, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Before the answer a piece of advice, never store localized timezones. Always store dates in UTC and convert on the application as needed.

`get_localzone()` is probably picking up the server timezone, yours is in whatever you call local timezone while heroku server is probably set to UTC. You have a few options:

#### 1) Set your server timezone to whatever you want

I'm not 100% sure this will work but maybe it's worth trying. Maybe setting the TZ variable to your desirable timezone will make that the local timezone. Try using:

```
heroku config:add TZ="America/Los_Angeles"
```

Replacing with your desired [timezone from this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

#### 2) Force django to use the timezone that you want

This might be a better option since you won't have to remember to set the timezone again in case you change providers or change the heroku server.

Instead of using get_localzone() pass in the name of the timezone you want directly like this:

```
timezone.activate(pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
```

I'm assuming you always want to use the same timezone throughout your application, but if you want to allow the user to select it's own timezone you can store that value in the user session or profile. [The Django docs has some good resources on this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/).